# What would be the best way to build an Ad rotator?

Tags: templating, best-practice

What would be the best way to build an Ad rotator similar to those we usually see around from http://fusionads.net for example.

WordPress have a plugin/widget for adding ads: https://wordpress.org/plugins/ad-rotator/

Basically it shows random HTML code every time you refresh the page.

I was wondering how we can do that with Craft.

Answer (score 4):

I built a plugin which does exactly this... **[Ad Wizard](https://www.doublesecretagency.com/plugins/ad-wizard)**.

You can put your ads into groups, and add that group to your template like this:

```
{{ craft.adWizard.position('rightSidebar') }}
```

That code will automatically display a random ad from the group (unless it's disabled, expired, or over its maximum allowed impressions).

You can also target a single ad specifically, by referring to its ID number:

```
{{ craft.adWizard.ad(42) }}
```

The plugin also gives you built in ad tracking... You can add [two chart widgets](https://www.doublesecretagency.com/plugins/ad-wizard/docs/seeing-your-ad-statistics) to your dashboard which will show you statistics on how your ads are doing.

If you need any help, feel free to contact support@doublesecretagency.com... All feedback, bug reports, and feature requests are welcome!

Comment: Great! Feel free to contact me with any feedback or issues. :)

Answer (score 3):

You build this in a couple different ways but the simplest would be to setup ads as as channel with an asset for the add, url etc. In the template you could set the ad [the entry] to appear randomly by using shuffle().

Comment: Ahh, awesome: [shuffle()](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/functions#shuffle). Thanks Adam!